# jQuery Mobile slider refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, slider

I have a range input like this:

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="7" step=".5" name="slider" id="slider" value="0" required="required" />
```

jQueryMobile auto initializes this and draws a slider. Then I try to update the its value programatically.

```
$("#slider").val(2) ;
$("#slider").slider('refresh') ;
```

But I get an error about the slider not ben initialized. I then initialize the slider before refreshing but jQM draws a second slider.

```
$("#slider").slider().slider('refresh') ;
```

How can I update a slider that has been auto-initialized and have it refresh?

[UPDATE]

I have found a workaround by setting data-role="none" so that JQM does not initialize. I also changed input type from range to number. I then initialize the slider programatically.

```
<input type="number" data-role="none" min="0" max="7" step=".5" name="slider" id="slider" value="0" required="required" />

$("#slider").slider() ;
```

Comment: Were you trying to call the original code before the pagecreate event?  As long as you call it at the right time, it works fine. See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/cutLejpw/

Comment: If you want the default value to be 2, just change `value` Statically from 0 to 2. There is no need to refresh it. As @ezanker said, most probably you're refreshing before slider is initialized.

Comment: I stumbled upon this Stackoverflow Q when wondering why my slider wasn't firing its slidestop event.  Turns out it was - but for the second slider that had been initialized programmatically instead, thus my event handler was not attached to the right slider!  Thanks!